# use explicit type to limit visibility of method in object to the module defining it

Tags: types, ocaml

I have a coordinate "class" (implemented using a factory function returning an object literal) in OCaml and am trying to figure out how to restrict the visibility of a method on that object to the module it was defined in.

Here's the source file

```
(* coordinate.ml *)
type coordinate = < get_x : int; get_y : int >

let create_coord ~x ~y = object
  val x = x
  val y = y
  method get_x = x
  method get_y = y
  (* hide this method from public interface *)
  method debug_print = Printf.printf "(x=%d, y=%d)\n"
end
```

and here's the interface

```
(* coordinate.mli *)
(* the type synonym coordinate is compatible with the "real"
 * type, but does not expose the debug_print method *)
type coordinate = < get_x : int; get_y : int >

val create_coord : x:int -> y:int -> coordinate
```

My intent was to allow the object returned by `create_coord` to have all of methods visible inside the body of the `Coordinate` module. The only reason the `coordinate` type alias is repeated in the `.ml` file is to satisfy the compiler/allow it to be used in the `.mli`.

However, I want to prevent consumers of this module from using the `debug_print` method. I figured that, "since OCaml supports structural typing", an object type with strictly fewer methods would be a "compatible" type for the purposes of type ascription.

However, when I attempt to compile the files I get the following error:

```
$ ocamlc coordinate.mli
$ ocamlc coordinate.ml
File "coordinate.ml", line 1:
Error: The implementation coordinate.ml
       does not match the interface coordinate.cmi:
       Values do not match:
         val create_coord :
           x:'a ->
           y:'b ->
           < debug_print : int -> int -> unit; get_x : 'a; get_y : 'b >
       is not included in
         val create_coord : x:int -> y:int -> coordinate
       File "coordinate.ml", line 3, characters 4-16: Actual declaration
Exit 2
```

Is there a way to limit the visibility of `debug_print` outside of `Coordinate` while making it freely accessible inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to use private row type:

```
module M : sig
  type t = private < x : int; y : int; .. >
  val make : int -> int -> t
  val f: t -> unit
end = struct
  type t = < x : int; y : int; z : [`Not_exposed] >

  let make x y = object
    method x = x
    method y = y
    method z = `Not_exposed
  end

  let f o =
    (* Access a method not exposed outside of the module *)
    assert (o#z = `Not_exposed)
end;;
```

This way, you don't need any coercion function. Still, any object of type `t` is seen with his private methods inside module M, but only the public one (`x`and `y`) can be accessed outside. Find more information in the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/privatetypes.html#ss:private-rows).

Answer (score 2):

You can make some of this work with an explicit coercion.  A minimal example:

```
type t = < x : int; y : int >
let make x y : t =
  let o =
    object
      method x = x
      method y = y
      method z = `Not_exposed
    end
  in
  (o :> t)

(* val make : int -> int -> t = <fun> *)
```

That still hides `z` inside of the module.  You can get a bit further by shadowing `make`:

```
module M : sig
  type t = < x : int; y : int >
  val make : int -> int -> t
end = struct
  type t = < x : int; y : int >

  let make x y = object
    method x = x
    method y = y
    method z = `Not_exposed
  end

  let f o =
    (* Access a method not exposed outside of the module *)
    assert (o#z = `Not_exposed)

  (* Shadow the make function, coercing the result into type t *)
  let make x y =
    (make x y :> t)
end
```

but this will not allow you to expose `f` as `t -> unit` as `t` does not have a `z` method.

You could also expose two types, keeping the full object type abstract outside of the module's context and providing a function to coerce/convert to the exposed, more restricted type:

```
module M : sig
  type t = < x : int; y : int >
  type opaque

  val make : int -> int -> opaque

  val f : opaque -> unit

  val of_opaque : opaque -> t
end = struct
  type t = < x : int; y : int >
  type opaque = < t; z : [`Not_exposed] >

  let make x y = object
    method x = x
    method y = y
    method z = `Not_exposed
  end

  let f (o : opaque) =
    assert (o#z = `Not_exposed)

  let of_opaque (o : opaque) : t =
    (o :> t)
end
```

Comment: I think that limits visibility inside the `Coordinate` module too. I still want to be able to call `debug_print` on objects created using `make`/`create_coord` inside the module. In order to do that, do I need two functions ... one which isn't exported and doesn't use `:> t` and the other which exported and does use `>: t`?

Comment: Edited with some updates about that - in short, yes!

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I have found that it is possible to use an explicit polymorphic type and an explicit upcast to convince OCaml that it is okay to "forget" a method.

```
type kata = < foo : int; bar : string >
type ana = < foo : int >

let to_ana (k : < foo : int ; .. >) : ana = (k :> ana)
```

This works well with polymorphic code.

```
to_ana (object method foo = 42 method bar = "asdf" method baz = [] end)
```

Comment: What would the type for `to_ana` look like in the corresponding `mli` file?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `mli` files well. I think that the key is to give `to_ana`'s argument an open object type, with `..`, so that the type-checker knows to expect wider objects with extra methods.